# jQuery failed to append JSON data as select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML structure :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 p-l-0">
      <div class="form-group form-group-default form-group-default-select2 required">
        <select disabled class="kurir">
        <option select="selected"></option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group form-group-default form-group-default-select2 required">
        <select disabled class="tarif">
        <option select="selected"></option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I also have this javascript :

```
$(".kurir").change(function() {

    var json_url = "some url here";

    $.getJSON( json_url, function( data ) {
        var tarif_items = [];
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            tarif_items.push( "<option value='" + key + "'>" + val + "</option>" );
        });

        $(this).parent().parent().next().find('.tarif').append(tarif_items);
    });
});
```

I can get `key` and `val` perfectly from JSON data, but why I still get empty option in `.tarif`? why jquery failed to append `tarif_items`? thank you so much.

Comment: Do you mean that there is one empty options, while your options from jQuery are also available or are none of the options from jQuery available? Is anything printed to the error console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because you are trying to append an `array` instead of an HTML `string`.

To fix this:

```
var $this = $(this);

$.getJSON( json_url, function( data ) {
    var tarif_items = "";
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        tarif_items += "<option value='" + key + "'>" + val + "</option>";
    });

    $this.parent().parent().next().find('.tarif').append(tarif_items);
});
```

I also suggest you to add an `id` attribute to that select like

```
<select id="tarif" disabled class="tarif">
  <option select="selected"></option>
</select>
```

And change the code like this

```
// $this.parent().parent().next().find('.tarif').append(tarif_items);
$('#tarif').append(tarif_items);
```

and finally, as a final improvement. I suggest you to do make a reset to avoid further issues:

HTML:

```
<select id="tarif" disabled class="tarif">
  <!-- no default option -->
</select>
```

JS:

```
$.getJSON( json_url, function( data ) {
    $('#tarif').html(''); // this resets the select content each time we receive the json
    var tarif_items = "<option select="selected"></option>"; // here it goes
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        tarif_items += "<option value='" + key + "'>" + val + "</option>";
    });

    $('#tarif').append(tarif_items);
});
```

This way you can also call the function multiple time and regenerate the select.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `this`, which doesn't belong to the selector as that is in the Ajax's context instead you should do this:

```
$(".kurir").change(function() {
    var $this = $(this); // <----+cache it here
    var json_url = "some url here";

    $.getJSON( json_url, function( data ) {
        var tarif_items = [];
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            tarif_items.push( "<option value='" + key + "'>" + val + "</option>" );
        });


         $this.closest('.col-sm-6.p-l-0')
                  .next().find('.tarif')
                  .append(tarif_items[0]);
         // now use it here.
    });
});
```